# Запись нескольких абзацев со своими шрифтами и размерами текста, жирностью и курсивами в одну строку, с помощью interop.word на C#

Tags: c#, office-interop, textformat

Есть название книги и её автор, к примеру:

### **Рэй Брэдбери**

*Вино из одуванчиков*

Как с помощью *interop.word* сделать так, чтобы текст в этом примере был с текущим форматом на 1 абзаце\строке в Word документе?

Заранее, спасибо за помощь!

**Пример кода:**

```
using System;
using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;

static void CreateText()
        {
            var wApp = new Word.Application();
            var missing = Type.Missing;
            var wDoc = wApp.Documents.Add(ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
            var para = wDoc.Paragraphs.Add(ref missing);

            para.Range.Text = "Ray Bradbury";
            para.Range.Font.Size = 14;
            para.Range.Font.Name = "Times New Roman";
            para.Range.Font.Bold = 1;
            para.Range.InsertParagraphAfter();

            para.Range.Text = "Dandelion Wine";
            para.Range.Font.Size = 8;
            para.Range.Font.Name = "Arial";
            para.Range.Font.Italic = 1;
            para.Range.InsertParagraphAfter();

            wDoc.SaveAs(@"E:\Projects\IntegraSred(Word)\IntegraSred(Word)\Файл1");


            object save_changes = false;
            wDoc.Close(ref save_changes, ref missing, ref missing);
            wApp.Quit(ref save_changes, ref missing, ref missing);
        }
```

Comment: Что именно не получается?

Comment: "Перенос" текста с сохранением их формата (шрифтов, размеров кегля, курсивом/жирностью) с 2мя и более абзацами под 1 строку. У каждого слова свой, отличный от другого формат.

Comment: _Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе._

Comment: Фрагмент рабочей части кода написан - выше. Ваш вопрос не совсем понятен мне, ибо я расписал и суть проблемы и сам пример кода того, с чем необходима помощь.

Comment: Вставьте код в сам вопрос, чтобы его можно было скопировать и запустить и объясните, что с этим кодом не так. Так понятнее?

Comment: З.ы. Запомнил, как делать описание вопроса. 
Спасибо, aepot!

Comment: До сих пор непонятнл, что не так. Вопрос только в том чтобы в одну строку это написать и всё? Вставляйте текст в один параграф, а не в разные.

Comment: В одну строку со *своими* шрифтами и кеглями текста. 

Если вы знаете как это решить, напишите строку кода, желательно проверив его перед этим.